# Custom background image or gradient for status bar in android 4 possible?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to add a custom background image or gradient for the status bar in android 4? Not android 5 and not a solid color.

Maybe someone know a solution?

Comment: It is not possible to draw anything behind status bar for APIs before Kit-Kat (19).